# TypeError in qx.ui.mobile.core.EventHandler after update to qooxdoo 1.5

Tags: qooxdoo

After updating to qooxdoo 1.5 I am seeing this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Expecting a function in instanceof check, but got #<HTMLDocument>

:8080/qooxdoo-1.5-sdk/framework/source/class/qx/ui/mobile/core/EventHandler.js?nocache=0.38786523090675473:245
```

Strange thing is, that I am not using the qx.ui.mobile.* classes at all. This is with a source-all build and "qx.debug" set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for including the qx.ui.mobile.* classes, this comes from using the `source-all` job, which includes, well, *all* known classes, also the qx.ui.mobile.* ones. Try using the normal `source` job, which only includes the classes necessary for your app.

As for the error, please open a bug report at http://bugzilla.qooxdoo.org. Please specify the OS and browser you are using when you get the error. If possible, supply a minimal Application.js (or a [Playground](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/1.5/playground) link) that reproduces the error. Cheers.

Comment: Ah, alright. I switched to the "source-hybrid" job now and it's gone. Will try to find a small sample, that reproduces the error.